# Request for feedback on proof [Linear Algebra]

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am a novice to higher-level math and would be grateful for feedback on this proof. I was able to complete the first 18 problems or so in section 3.B and confirm their validity by reviewing the solutions online, but #20 proved to be a bigger challenge.

The following exercise can be found in Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right 3e, section 3.B #20:

> Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$. Prove that $T$ is injective if and only if there exists $S \in \mathcal L(W,V)$ such that $ST$ is the identity map on V.

My proof:

Suppose $T$ is injective and let $w_1,..., w_n$ be a basis of $W$. Then for $v \in V$, we have $Tv = c_1w_1 + ... + c_nw_n$. By definition of range, this implies that $Tv = c_1Tv_1 + ... + Tv_n$, where $v_1, ..., v_n \in V$.

Since $T$ is a linear map, this means $Tv = T(c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n)$. Because $T$ is also injective, this implies $v = c_1v_1 + ... + c_nv_n$. Now $v$ is an arbitrary element of $V$, so $V \subset v_1,..., v_n$. But also, $v_1,..., v_n \in V$, thus $V = \operatorname{span}(v_1,..., v_n)$. Therefore, $V = \operatorname{span}(v_1,..., v_n)$, which implies $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Now let $u_1,..., u_m$ be a basis of $V$. Since $T$ is injective, we must have that $\dim V \le \dim W$.

Since $V$ and $W$ are finite vector spaces over $\Bbb F$, there exists a linear map $T: V \to W$ such that $Tv_j = w_j$ for $1 \le j \le m$. Since $T$ is injective, $Tv_j$ is unique for $w_j$.

Thus, $T(c_1u_1 + ... + c_mu_m) = c_1w_1 + ... + c_nw_n$ for arbitrary $v \in V$. Let $S(w_j) = u_j$ (which exists for the same reason $T$ exists) and $S(w_j)$ to $S(w_n) = 0$, which is uniquely determined since $T$ was injective.

Then $S(c_1w_1 + ... + c_nw_n) = c_1u_1 + ... + c_mu_m = v$ for any $v \in V$. This shows that $ST(v) = v$ for all $v \in V$.

Next, suppose there exists a linear map $ST$ such that $ST$ is the identity map on $V$.

For $v, u \in V, ST(v) = ST(u)$ is equivalent to $S(Tv) = S(Tu)$, which implies $v = u$ (otherwise $ST$ would not be the identity map). Thus, we have that $Tv = Tu$ implies $u = v$, so we conclude $T$ is injective, as desired.

Comment: I tried to edit the question the best way but there are some things that are not so clear... by example, what means $V\subset v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$? You probably means $V\subset\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$, right?

Comment: The first part seems correct but the wording is not so clear. However the second part seems not correct because the statement $$S(Tv)=S(Tu)\implies v=u$$ is not saying something. The assumption is that $ST=I$, then $STv=STu$ clearly means that $u=v$, but this doesnt says something about $T$. I solved both parts of this exercise using the fundamental theorem of linear algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of criticisms.

Your proof that the existence of $S$ implies injectivity seems mostly solid. I would like to see a more clear progression from the assumption that $Tu = Tv$ to the conclusion $u = v$. But I'm satisfied that you know what you're doing.

In your other proof, I notice that you assume $W$ is the range. All you can conclude from $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is that $W$ is the codomain. There may not be vectors $v_i$ that map to $w_i$ (which I can only assume is what the $v_i$ refer to). However, most of this can be rectified if you work with the range instead of the codomain; call it $W'$ or something. Then your argument that $T$ is finite-dimensional works.

Finally, I'm not sure what the statement "...which exists because $T$ exists" refers to. I think you're referring to the fact that linear maps are defined uniquely by their action on any given basis (which is good; you should refer to that), but I think that could be made clearer.

Other than that, it seems good!